# Java ResultSet nex() return false

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I'm new here, I looked for something similar, but I have not found.

Here is my code to get List of mPessoas, however it's returning only 1 record, but there are more records.

```
public class PessoasDAO {

public static List<ObjectsBD> getAll(String sql) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    List<ObjectsBD> mPessoasList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        conn = Conexao.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        Pessoas mPessoas = new Pessoas();
        Logradouro mLogradouro = new Logradouro();
        Bairro mBairro = new Bairro();
        Cidade mCidade = new Cidade();
        Estado mEstado = new Estado();
        Pais mPais = new Pais();

        while (rs.next()) {
            mPessoas.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            mPessoas.setNome(rs.getString(2));
            mLogradouro.setId(rs.getInt(3));
            mBairro.setId(rs.getInt(4));
            mCidade.setId(rs.getInt(5));
            mEstado.setId(rs.getInt(6));
            mPais.setId(rs.getInt(7));
            mLogradouro.setNome(rs.getString(8));
            mBairro.setNome(rs.getString(9));
            mCidade.setNome(rs.getString(10));
            mEstado.setNome(rs.getString(11));
            mPais.setNome(rs.getString(12));

            mPessoas.setLogradouro(mLogradouro);
            mPessoas.setBairro(mBairro);
            mPessoas.setCidade(mCidade);
            mPessoas.setEstado(mEstado);
            mPessoas.setPais(mPais);

            mPessoasList.add(mPessoas);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("ERRO: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("ERRO: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return mPessoasList;
}
}
```

Here mySQL Query;

```
SELECT p.*, l.nome AS logradouro, b.nome AS bairro, c.nome AS cidade, e.nome AS estado, pa.nome AS pais FROM pessoas AS p INNER JOIN logradouro AS l ON p.logradouroIdLogradouro = l.idLogradouro INNER JOIN bairro AS b ON p.bairroIdBairro = b.idBairro INNER JOIN cidade AS c ON P.cidadeIdCidade = c.idCidadeINNER JOIN estado AS e ON p.estadoIdEstado = e.idEstado INNER JOIN pais AS pa ON p.paisIdPais = pa.idPais ORDER BY p.nome ASC;
```

I Already tried, create a new Statement like,

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

but doesn't work.

I would appreciate it if anyone knows explain why this is happening.
thank you

Comment: That just means that there is no next value in the database. Are you sure that the value exists in the table? Are you sure you're using the correct database? Are you sure you're using the correct table?

Comment: You are creating only one `Pessoas` object in your code and then adding that same object to your list for each row returned from the result set. If your SQL yields, say, 4 rows, I would expect the list to contain 4 references to the a `Pessoas` object corresponding to the last row retrieved. Also, are any errors printed from running your code?

Comment: @NonameSL,  I was connected to another database that there was only one record, it's incredible as I not checked it before posting.

Comment: After correcting the database connection, happened what was mentioned by @Ole V.V. So I created new objects and all it works well. Thank you guys!